# How can I drop duplicate permutations from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, permutation

I'm trying to take 3 columns from a big csv file and find the permutations in order to keep only the unique triplets and put it in another csv.

For example if I have:

```
[8,9,15]
[78,35,98]
[90,35,56]
[64,89,98]
[15,8,9]...etc
```

it has to find that the first triplet is the same as the fifth and keep only one of them. I have written the following, but it doesn't work.

```
 import csv
 reader=csv.reader(open('file1.csv','r'), delimiter = ',')
 writer=csv.writer(open('mynew.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')
 myset = set()
 for row in reader:
    if row[0] not in myset:
       writer.writerow(row)
    if row[1] not in myset:
       writer.writerow(row)
    if row[2] not in myset:
       writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I don't see you adding anything to myset. If it's empty, nothing you're reading in is going to be already in there.

Comment: It also doesn't look quite right that you check for each of the columns individually whether they are `not in myset`.  While this is a sufficient condition for the entire row not being a permutation of an already seen row, it is not a necessary one.  Consider for example the rows (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4) and (1, 3, 4).  None is a permutation of another but your code would [probably] not print the third one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
reader=csv.reader(open('file1.csv','r'), delimiter = ',')
writer=csv.writer(open('mynew.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')
myset = set()
for row in reader:
    print "adding %s" % row
    # a frozen set is hashable and can be inserted to a set
    # this assumes no duplicates exist within the row like 1,1,2,3,4 (two 1's)
    # (otherwise you'll have to hash the row yourself)
    myset.add(frozenset(row))
    print "set size: %d" % len(myset)

print myset
```